# How to limit joined rows (many-to-many association) in Sequelize ORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

There are two models defined by Sequelize: Post and Tag with many-to-many association.

```
Post.belongsToMany(db.Tag, {through: 'post_tag', foreignKey: 'post_id', timestamps: false});
Tag.belongsToMany(db.Post, {through: 'post_tag', foreignKey: 'tag_id',timestamps: false});
```

On a "tag" page I want to get tag data, associated posts and show them with pagination. So I should limit posts. But If I try limit them inside "include"

```
Tag.findOne({
    where: {url: req.params.url},
    include: [{
        model : Post,
        limit: 10
    }]
}).then(function(tag) {
    //handling results
});
```

I get following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Only HasMany associations support include.separate
```

If I try to switch to "HasMany" associations I get following error

```
Error: N:M associations are not supported with hasMany. Use belongsToMany instead
```

And from other side documentation says that limit option "only supported with include.separate=true". How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old but for those of you still experiencing this issue, there's a simple workaround.

Since Sequelize adds [custom methods](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations) to instances of associated models, you could restructure your code to something like this:

```
const tag = await Tag.findOne({ where: { url: req.params.url } });
const tagPosts = await tag.getPosts({ limit: 10 });
```

This would work the exact same way as your code but with limiting and offsetting possible.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same exact problem here. From what I gathered, to use limit/offset you need the include.separate, which isn't supported for belongsToMany associations yet, so what you're trying to do isn't supported at the time of this post.

There's already someone working on it, you can track it
[here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/4525).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question that has not been answered.

##### **To anyone still facing such an issue**,

As the previous answer mentions that the **belongsToMany** associations do not support limit or offset..

Move the limit and offset outside your include array when dealing with Many to Many relations, although you are already querying as findOne(), passing limit or offset on the outer level will be activated on the inner relations that you have in your includes array ONLY in Many-Many Relations

It will automatically handle the inner results limit and offset

```
Tag.findOne({
    where: {url: req.params.url},
    include: [{
        model : Post,
        limit: 10 ❌ ( only exists in hasMany() )
    }]
    limit:10, ✅ ( This will solve your issue )

}).then(function(tag) {
    //handling results
});
```

I hope this helps.