# How can I limit many-to-many relationships on Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, relationship

I have following associations:

> M:N relationship table

```
ProductCategory.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: 'productId' });
ProductCategory.hasMany(Category, { foreignKey: 'categoryId', required: true });
  
   Category.belongsToMany(Product, {
      through: {
        model: ProductCategory,
      },
      otherKey: 'productId',
      foreignKey: 'categoryId',
    });


Product.belongsToMany(Category, {
  through: {
    model: ProductCategory,
    unique: false,
  },
  otherKey: 'categoryId',
  foreignKey: 'productId',
});
```

When I invoke following method `CategoryModel.findAll({ include: [ {model: ProductModel, limit: 1} ] });` I get something like this:

"Only HasMany associations support include.separate"

Anyone knows how can I handle this and limit include (many-to-many) relationship?
If I remove limit everything works that's expected, I get categories with their associated products, but I want to limit products.

I will appreciate any help, regards.

Comment: Can you check if the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118914/how-to-limit-joined-rows-many-to-many-association-in-sequelize-orm) satisfies your requirement?

Comment: **CategoryModel.findAll({ include: [ {model: ProductModel} ] ,
limit: 1
});**
try like this



Check this link for detail [https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize still doesn't support limit on belongsToMany relations:

- issues [#8360](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8360) closed
- PR [#4376](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/4525) closed currently
  Workaround for your case as mentioned in this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118914/how-to-limit-joined-rows-many-to-many-association-in-sequelize-orm) Answer 1:

```
const categories = await CategoryModel.findAll();
const categoriedProductModels = await categories.getProductModels({limit:1});
```

Alternative questions are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726143/how-to-limit-includes-on-a-belongstomany-association-in-sequelize-js),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134363/limit-on-belongstomany-association-with-sequelize)

Answer (score -1):

```
CategoryModel.findAll({ 
              include: [ {model: ProductModel} ] , 
              limit: 1 
      });
```

This will help you.

For more details check this link https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html

Comment: this will limit the higher level model which is CategoryModel, not the included model